# Pandas Merge, can't get my dataframes to match up on the key correctly?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that I want to merge on a column named Channel ID, this column exists in both dataframes, of course. When I run the code the rows of data are not matched up correctly, not sure what the issue is. Here is my code:

```
def matchID_RC(rev,cost):
    rev['Channel ID']=rev['Channel ID'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
    cost['Channel ID']=rev['Channel ID'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
    rc = pd.merge(rev, cost, on='Channel ID', how = 'inner')
    return rc
```

EDIT: When I use pd.merge I am expecting the rows of the dataframe to match on Channel ID. For example, a single row would have Channel ID, Channel Name, Impressions, Fill Rate, Gross Rev, Impression Fees, Exchange Fees, Campaign, Ad Spend that correspond to the Channel ID in both the rev and cost dataframes. What ends up happening is that I am return a single dataframe where the rows do not match up on Channel ID and so there is a mismatch between the revenues and costs of each channel.

```
testr.ix[0]
Out[21]: 
Channel ID         115331
Channel Name         ADD1
Impressions             0
Fill Rate           0.00%
Gross Rev          $0.00 
Impression Fees    $0.00 
Exchange Fees      $0.00 
Name: 0, dtype: object

testc.ix[0]
Out[22]: 
Channel ID                101611
Campaign      CP_AMOB_LRX_101611
Ad Spend                 0.05251
Name: 0, dtype: object

testr.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 169 entries, 0 to 168
Data columns (total 7 columns):
Channel ID         169 non-null int64
Channel Name       169 non-null object
Impressions        169 non-null object
Fill Rate          169 non-null object
Gross Rev          169 non-null object
Impression Fees    169 non-null object
Exchange Fees      169 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(6)
memory usage: 10.6+ KB

testc.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 63 entries, 0 to 62
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Channel ID    62 non-null float64
Campaign      63 non-null object
Ad Spend      63 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 2.0+ KB

rc.head()
Out[32]: 
Channel ID Channel Name Abbr Ad Requests Impressions Fill Rate Gross Rev  
0      115331         ADD1  SP2           7           0     0.00%    $0.00    
1      110403         ADG1  SP1       4,009         159     3.97%    $1.13 
2      110405         ADG3  SP1       4,450         124     2.79%    $1.01
3      116105         ASH1  SP1     137,570       1,367     0.99%   $11.34
4      115053         ATM2  SP7           1           0     0.00%    $0.00

Gross ECpm Impression Fees Exchange Fees    EBAS Ad Spend Net Rev  
0     $0.00           $0.00         $0.00   $0.00    $0.00   $0.00    
1     $7.13           $0.04         $0.17   $0.92    $0.00   $0.92    
2     $8.15           $0.04         $0.15   $0.82    $0.00   $0.82    
3     $8.30           $1.36         $1.70   $8.28    $0.00   $8.28    
4     $0.00           $0.00         $0.00   $0.00    $0.00   $0.00    

    Campaign               Total Ad Spend  
0   CP_AMOB_LRX_101611         0.05251  
1   CP_CARS10_LR_774470         5.70325  
2   CP_CARS11_LR_774471         3.56922  
3   CP_CARS9_LR_774469         8.55138  
4   CP_MAE9.1_LR_775219         0.00451
```

Comment: You need to provide the input data for both your dfs, it's impossible to answer without seeing how they look

Comment: Does this help, or is more info needed?

Comment: @bpr, please show relevant lines of your two data frames, the result of the merging and add why you think it's wrong and what you would have expected. At the moment your question provides too little information to be answered properly.

Comment: Hope this is sufficient information?

Comment: Can you post the output of `testr.info()` and `testc.info()`

Comment: Well your problem is right there, the dtypes are different, it's int64 and float64 for Channel ID. What is the correct dtype or do you have `NaN` values in your `testc` df?

Comment: I thought the matchID_RC() function converted the datatype of each channel ID to int. I removed the NaN values from testc

Comment: @EdChum   Good catch.  Regarding a fix, matching on a float column is a bad idea 99.99% of the time (or more).  I would suggest using `astype(int)` instead of `convert_objects()`.  Since this is an inner join, rows with NaN for ID can be dropped (so you don't need the float type to handle NaNs anyway).

Comment: I am basically still just getting testc tacked onto testr, both dataframes come out sorted alphabetically (how they were originally inputted) rather than being matched on Channel ID. I've munged the dataframes to be free of NaN values and changed to astype(int)

Comment: A few things:  (1) while debugging, I would do this outside of a function.  (2) post a few lines of testc, testr, and rc (e.g. `testc.head()`).  (3) in your function you have this, which is probably wrong:  `cost['Channel ID']=rev['Channel ID']`.  Should be `cost[]=cost[]`, right?

Comment: I've shown, and have been looking, at testr and testc outside of a function.   thanks for your catch on the matchID_RC(). Now that I fixed that code so cost[]=cost[] the script won't run, I get a KeyError: 'Channel ID'

Comment: I'm confused.  You printed out `rc.head()` and that looks right to me.  What is wrong with it?  It appears to contain variables from both datasets, so isn't that a successful merge result?

Comment: @JohnE It is merged, but the data is not correct. The Channel ID should match the 6 digit number in the 'Campaign Column' - that number is the Channel ID - this current result is not helpful to me.

Comment: Man, this has gotten too hard to follow.  I would suggest reposting but being super clear in the following ways:  post data before and after merge, show EXACT code you are running, and then show results after running code and EXACTLY what is wrong.